# Accessing JSON File with Multiple Hierarchical Layers

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a JSON file with the format below:

```
{  
   "total_rows":10000,
   "offset":0,
   "rows":[  
      {  
     "id":"005584833b8e2063f04ff713",
     "key":"00558433b8e2063f04ff713",
     "value":{  
        "rev":"1-8137baa51a2f335b0215ba9d08"
     },
     "doc":{  
        "_id":"0055842eb0063f04ff713",
        "_rev":"1-8137baa51a2f335b0215ba9d08",
        "value":1,
        "date":"2017-04-07T12:38:06.336Z",
        "date_inmilli":1491568686336,
        "sensorType":"sensor",
        "date":"2017-04-07T12:38:06.458Z"
     }
  }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to extract the values of `"sensorType"` or `"value"` using Python.
Using the R code below, I am able to get the results correctly:

```
library(jsonlite)
df <- fromJSON("file.json")
df$rows$doc$sensorType
```

However using Python `pandas`, I get an error when I try to exract the values with the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json("file.json")
df['rows']['doc']['sensorType']
```

I am trying to learn *Python*, could you help about this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rows` is a list of objects try this:

```
df['rows'][0]['doc']['sensorType']
```

or if you have many objects in the `rows` list you need to use `for loop statment`

```
for row in df['rows']:
    print(row['doc']['sensorType'])
```

**Update**
To put those values to a dataframe more pythonic way is this

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([row['doc']['sensorType'] for row in df['rows']])

print(df1)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the answer! Eventually I will put those values to a dataframe, is the code below the correct way in Python or is there a more optimal way?     df1 = []
for row in df['rows']:
    df1.append((row['doc']['sensorType']))
df1=pd.DataFrame(df1)

Comment: @Solijoli you can use `list comprehension` it is fastest that a simple `foor loop`, i update my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use python dict get method :

You can check all available method of any object by printing dir (object) :

```
print(dir(dict))

['__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'items', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values']
```

Uses:

```
data={
   "total_rows":10000,
   "offset":0,
   "rows":[
      {
     "id":"005584833b8e2063f04ff713",
     "key":"00558433b8e2063f04ff713",
     "value":{
        "rev":"1-8137baa51a2f335b0215ba9d08"
     },
     "doc":{
        "_id":"0055842eb0063f04ff713",
        "_rev":"1-8137baa51a2f335b0215ba9d08",
        "value":1,
        "date":"2017-04-07T12:38:06.336Z",
        "date_inmilli":1491568686336,
        "sensorType":"sensor",
     }
  }
   ]
}


print(data.get('rows')[0].get('doc').get('sensorType'))
```

output:

```
sensor
```

for pandas you can create a new dataframe and update it with for loop something like this:

```
raw_data = []

raw_data.append(data.get('rows')[0].get('doc').get('sensorType'))

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['sensorType'])

print(df)
```

output:

```
  sensorType
0     sensor
```